# given $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$ prove $f(z) = z^{1/3}$ is not entire.

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't want the solution at all, but I'm incredibly stuck, and I really need *some* (hopefully not much) help.

**What I've considered**:

1. Liouville's Theorem

Not applicable because f is not bounded.

2. Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Seems unlikely. We did not derive these for polar z in class, and the derivation is complex (for our level.) It is difficult/ impossible to talk about the partial derivatives of f without going through a similar ordeal.

3. Power series expansion

Not a viable path without being able to talk meaningfully about the $n^{th}$ derivative of f.

4. Finding holes in the function

The cube root has no holes on the reals, so it does not appear there are any holes in this function.

In conclusion, I'm very lost at the moment. Any guidance would be very much appreciated

Comment: It's not even continuous (along the negative real axis).

Answer (score 1):

For a function $f:\>{\mathbb C}\to{\mathbb C}$ to be entire it should at least be analytic in a full neighborhood of $z=0$. But this is not the case for the function "defined" by the typographical painting $f(z):=z^{1/3}$. Such a function would have to satisfy  $\bigl(f(z)\bigr)^3=z$, hence  $f(0)=0$, and $|f(z)|=|z|^{1/3}$. This then would imply
$$\lim_{z\to0}\left|{f(z)-f(0)\over z-0}\right|=\lim_{z\to0}|z|^{-2/3}=\infty\ ,$$
which is untenable.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* An entire function is holomorphic in $\Bbb C$, in particular it is
continuous. What happens at a point $z_0$ on the negative real axis?
Can you find a sequence $(z_n)$  converging to $z_0$
such that $f(z_n)$ does not converge to $f(z_0)$?

Comment: how did you come up with the thought to consider elements on the negative real axis?

Comment: @Hunter: That is where the "jump" in your definition of the argument is.  If you define the argument to be in the range $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$ then $\arg z$ can be close to $\pi$ or close to $-\pi$ if you approach a point on the negative real axis, depending on from where you approach it.